# AWS: Alarm when I leave an EC2 instance running?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I playing around with EC2 on some non-free VM's. I'd like to set up an alarm that will email me every, say, 24 hours that a VM is running, to remind me in case I forget to shut one down. Can this be done?

I'm reasonably confident that it probably can be, but I have no idea how.

Comment: You can set up a *cron job* that periodically sends you emails (or pretty much anything you want).

Answer (score 2):

You can setup Alarm based on resource usage and send an email to you (or) shutdown. Here is documentation on [how to Create Alarms to Stop, Terminate, Reboot, or Recover an Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html)

Comment: This is correct.  The service is CloudWatch and you want an Alarm.

Comment: Problem is, like the OP, I don't want an alarm to stop, terminate, reboot, or recover. I want one that, say every 12 hours, says "hey dummy ... you know you have an EC2 instance running and racking up a bill?"

Comment: May be you can try something like Lambda to SNS -> Lambda to check EC2 status? or create an metric alert if CPU > 0% for 12 hours send SNS email? few ideas I have. Are those cost efficient? - no idea.